# title seo tips on a tag and img tag

Tags: html, image, seo

in this code:

```
<a title="a title" href="big_photo.jpg"><img title="img title" src="photo.jpg" /><a/>
```

which "title" I must use in code for seo?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `title` **attribute** will not have any effect on Search Engine Optimization. Search engines are known to use the `alt` attribute however. The `alt` attribute actually describes the images and the text is used as an alternative in the case the browser is unable to display the image.
Correct usage for the given piece of code would be:

```
    <a href="big_photo.jpg"><img alt="Image Description" src="photo.jpg"/></a>
```

The `title` **tag**, as Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan mentioned, however is used for Search Engine Optimization. As it is the title of the page and used for title of the indexed page in the search results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the SEO talks about this title. I think they talk about this one:

```
<title></title>
```

However the title here would be the Description of the Element. Something like this:

```
title="A big photo"
```